# Como mostrar todo los articulos de una venta? Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-4

Tengo una duda de realizar una consulta donde me muestre la venta con sus articulos vendidos.

**actualmente tengo esta consulta:**

```
$query=trim($request->get('serachText'));
    $ventas=DB::table('venta as v')
    ->join('persona as p', 'v.cliente','=','p.idpersona')
    ->join('detalle_venta as dv','v.idventa','=','dv.venta')
    ->join('articulo as a','dv.articulo','=',"a.idarticulo")

    ->select('v.idventa','v.fecha_hora','p.nombre','v.tipo_comprobante','v.serie_comprobante','v.num_comprobante','v.impuesto','v.estado', 'v.total_venta','a.nombre')
    ->where('v.num_comprobante','LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
    ->orderBy('v.idventa','desc')

    ->paginate(7);
    return view('ventas.venta.index',["ventas"=>$ventas,"searchText"=>$query]);
```

Con la anterior consulta me muestra las ventas pero si por ejemplo tengo una venta de un cliente con varios articulos me repite la informacion, como muestro en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Esta es la base de datos relacional:**

[image: MER]

por ultimo este es el codigo de la vista:

```
@extends('layoust.admin')
@section ('contenido')
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <h3>
        Listado de Ventas
        <a href="venta/create">
            <button class="btn btn-success">
                Nuevo
            </button>
        </a>
    </h3>
    <!--se incluye la vista search, que es una barra de busqueda-->
    @include('ventas.venta.search')
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <th>
                    Fecha
                </th>
                <th>
                    Cliente
                </th>
                <th>
                    Comprobante
                </th>
                <th>
                    Impuesto
                </th>
                <th>
                    Total
                </th>
                <th>
                    Articulo
                </th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Opciones</th>
            </thead>
            <!--Bucle que recorre todas los ingresos-->
            @foreach ($ventas as $vent)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ $vent->fecha_hora}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ $vent->nombre}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ $vent->tipo_comprobante.": ".$vent->serie_comprobante."-".$vent->num_comprobante}}
                </td>
                 <td>
                    {{ $vent->impuesto}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$vent->total_venta}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$vent->nombre}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$vent->estado}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{URL::action('VentaController@show',$vent->idventa)}}">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">
                            Detalles
                        </button>
                    </a>
                    <a data-target="#modal-delete-{{$vent->idventa}}" data-toggle="modal" href="">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">
                            Anular
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!--modal de eliminar-->
            @include('ventas.venta.eliminar')
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
    <!--mostrar paginacion con el metodo render-->
    {{$ventas->render()}}
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Creo que lo que tienes son las ventas duplicadas en la tabla ventas, no es que la consulta te repita los datos. Parece como es como si por cada detalle insertará también una venta.

Comment: @Xerif Tienes razon fue error mio.